# How to make a pivot table from a dataframe with multiple columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, pivot-table

Please help me.

My dataframe looks like this:

| **date** | **account** | **action** |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | 504 | login |  |  |
| 2021-01-11 | 504 | edit_profile |  |  |
| 2021-01-11 | 504 | logout |  |  |
| 2021-01-12 | 11 | login |  |  |
| 2021-01-12 | 11 | login |  |  |
| 2021-01-14 | 303 | edit_profile |  |  |
| 2021-01-14 | 303 | logout |  |  |

What I want to achieve is this:

| **date** | **account** | **login** | **edit_profile** | **logout** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-11 | 504 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2021-01-12 | 11 | 2 | 0 | 0 |
| 2021-01-14 | 303 | 0 | 1 | 1 |

The first thing I thought about was pivot table, but the problem is that I don't have total count for certain 'account's daily actions. How to count the number of occurrences within a time range for each value? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For performance, try to avoid loops with pandas. There are plenty of vectorized functions:

```
import pandas as pd

#recreating your sample data
from io import StringIO
data1 = """
date         account   action         
2021-01-11     504     login         
2021-01-11     504     edit_profile         
2021-01-11     504     logout         
2021-01-12     11      login         
2021-01-12     11      login         
2021-01-14     303     edit_profile         
2021-01-14     303     logout
"""
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data1), sep = "\s{2,}", engine="python")
df["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["date"])


df1 = df.groupby(by=["date", "account", "action"]).size().unstack(fill_value=0)

print(df1)
```

Sample output:

```
action              edit_profile  login  logout
date       account                             
2021-01-11 504                 1      1       1
2021-01-12 11                  0      2       0
2021-01-14 303                 1      0       1
```

Please note that you now have a MultiIndex dataframe. You can remove the index levels by adding [`.reset_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html)

Comment: Very kind but I have only moderate insight into pandas. [Unstack is a pivot function](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), so you were heading in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Could this work?

Get the piece of dataframe during a certain period of time:

```
new_df = df[start_date < df['date'] < end_date]
```

new_df now has all the rows during a certain period of time.
Get all the unique account values:

```
accounts = new_df['account'].unique()
```

Then create a for loop to go through all of the accounts action:

```
# Dataframe that keeps track of the actions
actions_df 

for  account in accounts:
    # Get all the rows with certain user
    user_df = new_df[new_df['account'] == account]
    # We now have all the rows that has certain account in user_df
    for action in user_df['action']:
        if action == "login":
            actions_df[action_df['account'] == account]['login'] += 1
```

Now we have all the actions in action_df dataframe

Hope this helps in any way!

Comment: Hey, thank you so much for the help. I did what you said and it gave me a KeyError: 'account'. I'm confused. How is it possible that 'account' column doesn't exist?

Comment: Where in the code it throws this error?